# Deciphering binary in assembly

Tags: c, assembly

I am working on a part of an assignment which requires me to determine which parameters to pass into a function to skip over a certain function. This is the assembly code in question.

Here is the beginning of the function where it is moving one parameter into eax and performing arithmetic:

```
  0x080499ca <+0>:  push   %ebp
  0x080499cb <+1>:  mov    %esp,%ebp
  0x080499cd <+3>:  sub    $0x8,%esp
  0x080499d0 <+6>:  mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
  0x080499d3 <+9>:  sub    $0x37,%eax // subtract 55
  0x080499d6 <+12>: cmp    $0x13,%eax // compare against 19 
  0x080499d9 <+15>: ja     0x8049a4a <transform+128>
```

Starting out, the movzbl function moves the value of 0x804 (and zero extends it)... into the register. The binary value of this is: 001000000001001101001000111000

The "xor" compares this against the constant 1. The test takes the lowest 8 bits of eax, the register, with this new value:

```
0x08049a4a <+128>:  movzbl 0x804d238,%eax
0x08049a51 <+135>:  xor    $0x1,%eax
0x08049a54 <+138>:  test   %al,%al
0x08049a56 <+140>:  je     0x8049a5d <transform+147>
```

If the ZFLAG is set, then it jumps (which is what I want). I'm not sure why, though, with the same values each time, the flag would be any different based on what parameters I am passing into the WHOLE function. It seems that it should deliver the same outcome each time. Why is it that sometimes the flag is being set and sometimes it is not being set?

Also, what value could I put into the parameter to make sure that it jumps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

```
0x08049a4a <+128>:  movzbl 0x804d238,%eax
0x08049a51 <+135>:  xor    $0x1,%eax
0x08049a54 <+138>:  test   %al,%al
0x08049a56 <+140>:  je     0x8049a5d <transform+147>
```

...the `xor $0x01` flips bit 0 of the value loaded into `%eax`; the `test %al, %al` ands `%al` with itself (discarding the result, but keeping the effect on flags); so the `je` will be taken if `%al` was zero.  That is... the jump will be taken if `((value ^ 1) & 0xFF) == 0`.

Comment: So what kind of values would ensure that it was always 0? And also, isn't the value loaded into eax always the same, since it is always pointing to the same place? This was part of the original question.

Comment: It rather depends on what address 0x804d238 refers to.  If it refers to what we programmers call a variable, then its value need not always be the same.  Unless the memory is failing, one would expect the value read from a variable to be the value last written to it.  From this distance, I regret that I am unable to discern what 0x804d238 refers to in your program, or what was last written to it.  Any value which satisfies `((value ^ 1) & 0xFF) == 0` will do the trick.  (I hope this is understandable in a C context, but I regret I cannot think of a clearer way to express it.)